# Apache storm : Could not load main class org.apache.storm.starter.ExclamationTopology

Tags: java, jar, apache-storm

firstly I already referred quite a few similar questions but still haven't been able to fix it.
I have installed nimbus and supervisor properly and there were no errors while "make install" even maven clean install and compile had no errors at all, even my 0qm is set up properly with jzmq, and also started my nimbus by ./storm nimbus and started my supervisor by ./storm supervisor but when I do

> ./storm jar ~/ccbd-work/storm2/examples/target/storm-starter-topologies-0.10.0.jar org.apache.storm.starter.ExclamationTopology

I get the following error

> Running: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -client -Ddaemon.name= -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/home/hubatrix/ccbd-work/storm2/apache-storm-0.10.0 -Dstorm.log.dir=/home/hubatrix/ccbd-work/storm2/apache-storm-0.10.0/logs -Djava.library.path=/usr/local -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp /home/hubatrix/ccbd-work/storm2/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/log4j-core-2.1.jar:/home/hubatrix/ccbd-work/storm2/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:/home/hubatrix/ccbd-work/storm2/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:/home/hubatrix/ccbd-work/storm2/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/asm-4.0.jar:/home/hubatrix/ccbd-work/storm2/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar:/home/hubatrix/ccbd-work/storm2/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/minlog-1.2.jar:/home/hubatrix/ccbd-work/storm2/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/kryo-2.21.jar:/home/hubatrix/ccbd-work/storm2/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/disruptor-2.10.4.jar:/home/hubatrix/ccbd-work/storm2/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/home/hubatrix/ccbd-work/storm2/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/hadoop-auth-2.4.0.jar:/home/hubatrix/ccbd-work/storm2/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/log4j-api-2.1.jar:/home/hubatrix/ccbd-work/storm2/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.1.jar:/home/hubatrix/ccbd-work/storm2/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/clojure-1.6.0.jar:/home/hubatrix/ccbd-work/storm2/apache-storm-0.10.0/lib/storm-core-0.10.0.jar:/home/hubatrix/ccbd-work/storm2/examples/target/storm-starter-topologies-0.10.0.jar:/home/hubatrix/ccbd-work/storm2/apache-storm-0.10.0/conf:/home/hubatrix/ccbd-work/storm2/apache-storm-0.10.0/bin -Dstorm.jar=/home/hubatrix/ccbd-work/storm2/examples/target/storm-starter-topologies-0.10.0.jar org.apache.storm.starter.ExclamationTopology
>   Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.storm.starter.ExclamationTopology

what am I doing wrong here? Please help me fix this 
and also I am running this is on a local machine and my storm.yaml is configured properly.

here is my file structure of storm2 http://paste.linux.chat/view/e4424189 if at all I am doing anything wrong in defining correct me from it.

My every setup was right till the end as Matthias J. Sax mentioned I had issues with my jar file, but dont really know if the issue was jar file(topology) itself or the path I just download a new jar file from https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/kc933u6vz2crqkb/storm-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar and ran

> ./storm jar ~/ccbd-work/storm2/storm-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar storm.starter.WordCountTopology WordCount -c nimbus.host=localhost

and it worked like walk in a cake, thanks again for the response

Comment: Am I lacking any information ?

Comment: Are you sure that the jar file contains the class? You can check via `unzip -l yourJarFile.jar | grep Exclamation`.

Comment: `$ unzip -l storm-starter-topologies-0.10.0.jar | grep Exclamation
                   1921  2015-10-23 15:35   storm/starter/ExclamationTopology$ExclamationBolt.class
     2135  2015-10-23 15:35   storm/starter/ExclamationTopology.class
     1764  2015-10-23 15:35   storm/starter/ManualDRPC$ExclamationBolt.class`
 @MatthiasJ.Sax see its there, both my numbus and supervisor are running but cant put up the toplogy and also this is from the examples from storm-starter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not in the correct folder: the error messages says "org.apache.storm.starter.ExclamationTopology" but the class file is in folder "storm/starter". (In Java, package names must align with directory structure.)

`ExclamationTopology` was moved from package `storm.starter` to `org.apache.storm.starter` recently. In version 0.10.0 it is still in `storm.starter`. Thus, you need to submit your topology via

```
./storm jar ~/ccbd-work/storm2/examples/target/storm-starter-topologies-0.10.0.jar storm.starter.ExclamationTopology
```

Comment: @Matthis J. Sax I ran the same command and still I get `Error: Could not find or load main class storm.starter.ExclamationTopology` its not working.

Comment: That is weird... No idea what the problem might be. Sorry.

Comment: Just so you know I am running above command from following path from `~/ccbd-work/storm2/apache-storm-0.10.0/bin` where there is a excutable called storm*

Comment: Can you please help me with this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35776529/ @Matthias J. Sax

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this issue and confuse for two days. Then I found it is the wrong folder problem. The solution actually is quite easy. You don't need to add "org.apache.storm.starter" at the front. Which means all you need to do is to cd to the starter folder then run "storm jar ~/ccbd-work/storm2/examples/target/storm-starter-topologies-0.10.0.jar ExclamationTopology". That's all. Then you could check the topology at the localhost:8080. Good luck!