# Storm WordCount error: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken, no output read

Tags: java, python, apache-storm, topology

Storm 0.10.0
my previous question ([Apache storm : Could not load main class org.apache.storm.starter.ExclamationTopology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35525965/)) which was solved.

hello I have a single node cluster up and running on my machine, the storm config file is as follows:(storm.yaml)

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
#     - "server1"
#     - "server2"
  - "localhost" 
storm.zookeeper.port: 2181
nimbus.host: "localhost"
storm.local.dir: "/var/stormtmp" 
java.library.path: "/usr/local"
supervisor.slots.ports:
  - 6700
  - 6701
  - 6702
  - 6703
worker.childopts: "-Xmx768m"
nimbus.childopts: "-Xmx512m"
supervisor.childopts: "-Xmx256m"
```

and I ran this WordCount topology on the cluster (found the topology here and simply ran it) https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/kc933u6vz2crqkb/storm-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
(which is python)

but on of the bolt is throwing the following error at port 6703 localhost

> java.lang.RuntimeException: backtype.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read. Serializer Exception: at backtype.storm.utils.ShellProcess.readShellMs

So I figured something was wrong in the topology so checked my WordCount-3-1457017776-worker-6701.log (file) and found this:

```html
b.s.d.executor [INFO] TRANSFERING tuple TASK: 8 TUPLE: source: split:18, stream: default, id: {}, ["moon"]
b.s.d.executor [INFO] BOLT ack TASK: 18 TIME:  TUPLE: source: spout:25, stream: default, id: {}, [the cow jumped over the moon]
b.s.t.ShellBolt [INFO] ShellLog pid:1714, name:split Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/stormtmp/supervisor/stormdist/WordCount-3-1457017776/resources/storm.py", line 172, in run
    self.process(tup)
  File "splitsentence.py", line 5, in process
    words = tup.values[0].split(" ")
IndexError: list index out of range

b.s.t.ShellBolt [ERROR] Halting process: ShellBolt died. Command: [python, splitsentence.py], ProcessInfo pid:1714, name:split exitCode:0, errorString:
java.lang.RuntimeException: backtype.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.
Serializer Exception:

        at backtype.storm.utils.ShellProcess.readShellMsg(ShellProcess.java:101) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt$BoltReaderRunnable.run(ShellBolt.java:321) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_95]
b.s.d.executor [ERROR]
java.lang.RuntimeException: backtype.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.
Serializer Exception:

        at backtype.storm.utils.ShellProcess.readShellMsg(ShellProcess.java:101) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at backtype.storm.task.ShellBolt$BoltReaderRunnable.run(ShellBolt.java:321) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_95]
```

So I belive the index out of range(occured due to line 5, tuple becomming 0) is causing the bolt to die and the pipe to it is broken, so I am not able to do futher processing of data, Is my understanding about the issue correct ?
and is there a soulution to this ? or may be a different topology I can test on? Please help me out this is my first topology running on storm

Comment: Any more information required ?

Comment: where are you getting your topology from? your understanding is correct, though I tested the wordcount topology with no errors on my system... it may be that your jar file has been modified. The best thing would be for you to grab the source code of the storm starter package and compile it yourself to make sure what the code is doing. Your error is basically saying the tuple was empty, and it must have come like that from upstream in the topology, though without source code we cannot know where the error originated.

Comment: did you get the reason for this problem ?